# Get look angle at a specific coordinate on a SAR image

Tags: angles, sentinel-1, synthetic-aperture-radar

Can we get the look angle of the `SAR` sensor on a `large` image for a given `coordinate`, if we only have the `look angle` in the `mid-swath` (or the `near-range` & `far-range` angles)?

Do we get the `look angle` at a specific location by interpolation or is there a more precise method to estimate it?

If we take as an example of a `SAR sensor` `Sentinel-1`, the `look angle` changes inside the same image from a region to another, especially if the image is large (as is the case of the images taken by `Sentinel-1` in the `Interferometric Wide Swath` mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that `Sentinel-1` products are provided with a `tie point grids` having a map of `incident angles`.